# Use loop variable as part of new variable in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to assign a variable based on its loop variable value so that at the end of the loop i can echo out each result in a single line. The general command is an nslookup with multiple servers being queried. I'm grabbing out the beginning of the name result (up to first dot) to display the results based on 5 second delays. I left in a second version of the command i've also tried but rem'ed. I can't get the target to populate and echo either.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For %%s IN (111.111.0.2, 111.111.0.3, 111.111.9.2, 111.111.9.3) do (

for /L %%l IN (1,1,5) DO (

set Target=%e%%l.testedge.test.tld%

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%G IN ('nslookup e%%l.testedge.test.tld %%s  ^|find "Name:"') do set %Result%%l%=%%G

REM set Result%%l=%for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%G IN ('nslookup e%%l.testedge.test.tld %%s  ^|find "Name:"') do echo %%G%

REM for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%G IN ('nslookup e%%l.testedge.test.tld %%s  ^|find "Name:"') do set !Result%%1!=%%G

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul 

)

echo %%s,%Target%,%Result1%,%Result2%,%Result3%,%Result4%,%Result5%
)
```

The nslookup results look like

```
Name: e1.testedge.test.tld
Name: user-data.e1.testedge.test.tld
Name: user-data.e1.testedge.test.tld
```

So the for loop grabs e1, user-data, and user-data. I need to assign them to a persistent variable for echoing at the end of the loop. I plan on appending to a csv so we can open in spreadsheet form (Looking up over 70 addresses through 20 servers) for review. I would like the output to be like

```
Nameserver  Target              1st   2nd     3rd         4th        5th
111.111.0.2,e1.testedge.test.tld,e1,user-data,user-data,user-data,user-data
111.111.0.2,e2.testedge.test.tld,e2,user-data,user-data,user-data,user-data
111.111.0.2,e3.testedge.test.tld,e3,user-data,user-data,user-data,user-data
111.111.0.2,e4.testedge.test.tld,e4,user-data,user-data,user-data,user-data
```

Comment: NOTE: I changed the nslookup results to accurately represent the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

For %%s IN (111.111.0.2, 111.111.0.3, 111.111.9.2, 111.111.9.3) do (
    for /L %%l IN (1,1,5) DO (
        set "Target=e%%l.testedge.test.tld"
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%G IN ('nslookup !Target! %%s  ^|find "Name:"') do set "Result%%l=%%G"
    )
    echo %%s,!Target!,!Result1!,!Result2!,!Result3!,!Result4!,!Result5!
)
```